How to unit test a function (Windows API) that launches processes?
I've been tasked to use the Windows API (CreateProcessA, ExitProcess) to write a function that'll create, launch, and terminate some in-house applications (app1.exe, app2.exe). The two apps are fire-and-forget: once launched, they use an in-house/non-standard interprocess communication (IPC) mechanism to send messages to one another, including to the parent process.
In addition to carrying out their intended duties, each child process periodically send heartbeat messages to the parent to let them know they're still responsive.
The parent process has a handle to each child process and is responsible for restarting/reporting (to another process) whenever app1.exe or app2.exe fail to send it "heartbeat" messages.
I've written the function that'll start app1 and app2, and it correctly starts up app1 and app2. Following the documentation for CreateProcessA, I wrote some more code (i.e., GetLastError) to log system errors. I've ran the functions manually to see that app1 and app2 get launched but I don't know how to cause CreateProcessA to fail to test the logging of the system errors. The function is essentially this:
status LaunchApp1(...) 
{
   result = CreateProcessA(app1.exe,...);
   if (result == 0) {
      DWORD errCode = GetLastError(); // Per API
      string errMsg = ConvertErrCodeToStr(errCode); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/71588259/3396951
      Log(errMsg);
      status = FailedToLaunchApp1Enum;
   }
   else {
      status = SuccessfulLaunchApp1;
   }
}

status LaunchApp2(...) 
{
   // Same as LaunchApp1
}

With regards to unit testing, what should I check? Is checking that error-handling runs correctly within the scope of this task?


I don't know how to cause CreateProcessA to fail to test the logging of the system errors

You could try writing testable code.
status LogResult(result, DWORD errCode) 
{
   if (result == 0) {
 
      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/71588259/3396951
      string errMsg = ConvertErrCodeToStr(errCode);
      Log(errMsg);
      status = FailedToLaunchApp1Enum;
   }
   else {
      status = SuccessfulLaunchApp1;
   }
}

status LaunchApp1(...) 
{
   status = LogResult(CreateProcessA(app1.exe,...), GetLastError());
}

With this refactoring LaunchApp1 behaves the same as it ever did but now your tests are free to shove whatever results into LogResult that you like without having to worry about actually running anything. Should make it easy to get complete code coverage and confidence that the error handling does what you intend it to.
If you're not testing ConvertErrCodeToStr() directly you'll also want to mock Log so you can test the errMsg.

My Attempt To Answer These Questions
We focus on testing what we care about:

The function used to launch apps works to launch any simple app (we don't necessarily care that app1.exe or app2.exe that gets launched successfully)
Logging works when the function fails to launch any simple app (again, we don't care that the apps are app1.exe or app2.exe).

The rationale for testing the launch of a simple app and not app1.exe and app2.exe themselves is that we can't control whether these 2 apps will start up at all. But if we create a working simple app whose launch is always successful ("good app") and another simple app whose launch is always unsuccessful ("bad app"), and with them, test the function that launches processes, we can have confidence the problem isn't with the process-launching functionality.
So testing for #1 would involve using the function to launch a good app and have the good app confirm it's alive. Assert that the "status" flag reflects the process is running.
Testing for #2 would involve using the function to launch a bad app and checking that the log stores the expected output (e.g., point to an executable that can't be executed, or doesn't exist, or whatever condition is encapsulated by one of the error codes). Assert that the "status" flag reflects the process is not running.

This is the integration test approach. It's thorough but involved, slow, and flaky. But it can give you coverage.

The traditional approach is to create an interface class around the thing you are trying to mock. In your case you need to mock the behavior of the Windows API in order to test your error handling.
class IWinApi
{
public:
    virtual ~IWinApi() = default;
    virtual BOOL CreateProcess() = 0;
    // add all the other functions you need
};

You can have two implementations (subclasses) of this interface. One that actually calls the Windows API and another one which only mocks it.
class WinApi: public IWinApi
{
public:
    BOOL CreateProcess() override
    {
        return CreateProcessA(); // actually call the Windows API
    }
};

class WinApiMock: public IWinApi
{
public:
    BOOL CreateProcess() override
    {
        return 0; // simulate failure
    }
};

You can then modify the LaunchApp1 function to take a reference to IWinApi class and call its functions instead of calling the Windows API directly.
status LaunchApp1(IWinApi &winApi, ...) 
{
   result = winApi.CreateProcess();

In your real application you obviously need to provide the instance of the WinApi class (the one that actually calls the Windows API).
WinApi winApi;
LaunchApp1(winApi, ...);

In your tests, however, you need to provide the instance of the WinApiMock class (the one that simulates the failure).
WinApiMock winApi;
LaunchApp1(winApi, ...);

In your WinApiMock class you can of course add member variables and a constructor to control the behavior of the functions. Alternatively, consider using some testing framework, such as GoogleTest, which makes mocking easier.
